# Good tutorials for learning intermediate to advanced Regex?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

So I'm familiar with the basics of regex but am looking for good tutorials for learning anything beyond the basics. I'd also appreciate any links to interactive problems where I can type in regular expressions and see if they solve it.  Even ideas for intermediate or advanced problems I can try and solve through my own coding would be great.

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ground-zero for learning regular expressions:

[Regular Expression Tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 6):

"[Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/)", by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl. Yes, it's a book vs. an on-line tutorial, but a very good one...

Answer (score 5):

I can really recommend [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) along with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). Regexbuddy is a fantastic tool which helps you writing regex in various languages. It also has capabilities of explaining the regex for you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Regular-Expressions info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html) goes over every aspect of regular expressions.

Also are some [Advanced Regular Expression](http://wiki.tcl.tk/21360) **Examples** that users have posted to test your knowledge

Answer (score 2):

One program I always come back to is [RegexDesigner](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#regexd).  It's a very simple tool that let's you write, test, and save regexs; a lot like the above RegEx Buddy but simpler and free.  It also generates C# and VB.NET code.

Answer (score 2):

How about re-builder in emacs

[alt text http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9887/rebuilder.png](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9887/rebuilder.png)

Answer (score 2):

Intermediate to advanced regex?... Here it is.

http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/regexp/

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a Regex Library. It's not exactly what you asked for, but you might find useful anyway: http://regexlib.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is 
[Quick and advanced Regular Expressions tutorial for Python](http://www.cofoh.com/quick-advanced-re-tutorial-python)
which I've written recently. It covers lot of info in small size
and I put lot of effort to make it good.

Code snippets are loaded online if you prefer to tests it right-away.